opening port in Ubuntu
First time here, long time Noob
I am running an Ubuntu instance on Oracle Cloud, and I need to open a port due to a new device I have pointing to our server.
I ran the command sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target prot opt source destination
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT icmp -- anywhere anywhere
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere udp spt:ntp
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:8383
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW udp dpt:47701
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:47701
ACCEPT udp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW udp dpt:47764
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:47764
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere state NEW tcp dpt:https
REJECT all -- anywhere anywhere reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

I need to add port 47776. Can you advise on how I can do this please.
Thank you in advance,
Michael
